# cant project framebuffer for Reflection

Tags: reflection, projection, framebuffer, terrain

water reflection just using scaling glScalef(1, 1, -1) is being blocked by terrain under water.
So i think it would be better if reflection is first stored in framebuffer.
but how can i project the rendered texture on the water

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling depth test lets terrain not to block.